# Confused about the expression "I dwell confined"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, secondary-predicates

In the *Amazing Spiderman* movie, Dr. Curt Connors said:

> "I might be free to cast off flesh wherein I dwell confined."

What's the meaning of “I dwell confined” in this context?

Answer (score 3):

*Wherein I dwell confined* is a relative clause modifying *flesh*.

- *wherein* is a rather formal way of saying *in which*
- *dwell* is an old word meaning *live* in the sense *inhabit*, now little used outside of literature
- *confined* is the past participle of the verb *confine*, here employed as a secondary complement modifying the subject

> I dwell confined in flesh = I live enclosed by/imprisoned in flesh.

The relative clause is constructed by replacing the implicit object of *in* with *which* and moving both *which* and the preposition which governs it to the head of the clause:

> I dwell confined [in [flesh]] > [in [which]] I dwell confined

Answer (score 2):

We live in our skin. It constrains us – we can't be in two places at once.

The word *dwell* means *live*. The quote could rephrased:

> I live confined in my body; someday, I might be free to cast it off

That may be a little less confusing, but it's a little less poetic, too. There's no such thing as a [free lunch](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There%27s+no+such+thing+as+a+free+lunch).